# Index - Match like function in PL-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently I have very specific problem with data we get from our data-warehouse. The problem is being solved, but I have to edit our control environment for a while.

We have data about received invoices, however due to some reason, information about every invoice is split into two rows:  First row has important columns **unique_code_A**, **vendor_number**, and the second row has important columns **unique_code_B**, **amount**. So every invoice has very specific unique code, and with this code I have to somehow join the information from both rows, as you can see in picture.

[image: how my table looks vs. how i would like to see row]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use aggregation:

```
select date_key, invoice_type,
       max(case when unique_code_b is null then unique_code_a end) as unique_code_a,
       max(unique_code_b) as unique_code_b,
       max(case when unique_code_b is null then vendor_number end) as vendor_number,
       max(case when unique_code_b is not null then amount end) as amount
from t
group by date_key, invoice_type;
```

EDIT:

If the unique codes can be used for matching, then I would suggest:

```
select date_key, invoice_type,
       coalesce(unique_code_a, unique_code_b) as unique_code,
       max(case when unique_code_b is null then vendor_number end) as vendor_number,
       max(case when unique_code_b is not null then amount end) as amount
from t
group by date_key, invoice_type, coalesce(unique_code_a, unique_code_b);
```

Comment: I get the point of your answer (I think), but feel like the SQL you posted is just going to confuse the OP since it is likely that he has more than one distinct "unique code" value in a given date / invoice type.  I believe the unique_code should factor into your `GROUP BY` somehow.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak . . . I think you might be right, so I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what you told, a self join should probably work:

```
SELECT 
    A.DATE_KEY,
    A.INVOICE_TYPE,
    A.UNIQUE_CODE_A,
    B.UNIQUE_CODE_B,
    A.VENDOR_NUMBER,
    B.AMOUNT
FROM MyTable A 
INNER JOIN MyTable B ON A.UNIQUE_CODE_A=B.UNIQUE_CODE_B
```